# How to disable COD payment method based on product attribute value in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, product-attribute, payment-methods

Create a product attribute in BE: Engraving Services, input type: Yes/No.

On Checkout - step Payment Method page, check if in cart attribute Engraving
Services of valid products: Yes, Then disable Payment Method - COD (Cash On
Delivery)

[image]
[image]

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/catalog/product-attributes/create/attribute-product-create.html

I have followed the devdocs and created the product attribute, but I don't have a solution to disable the COD.

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you named `Magetu` as the vendor name, `EngravingServices` as the module name, and your custom product attribute named `engraving_services`.

### Declare a new observer in `events.xml`, and use `payment_method_is_active` event

File path: `app/code/Magetu/EngravingServices/etc/events.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="disable_cashondelivery_for_engraving_services_product" instance="MageTu\EngravingServices\Observer\DisableCashondeliveryForEngravingServicesProduct" />
    </event>
</config>
```

### Create the Observer class

File path: `app/code/Magetu/EngravingServices/Observer/DisableCashondeliveryForEngravingServicesProduct.php`

```
<?php
namespace Magetu\EngravingServices\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;

class DisableCashondeliveryForEngravingServicesProduct implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Disable Cash On Delivery payment method if the cart contains Engraving Services product
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var DataObject $result */
        $result = $observer->getResult();
        /** @var AbstractMethod $methodInstance */
        $methodInstance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
        /** @var CartInterface $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $paymentCode = $methodInstance->getCode();

        if ($paymentCode === Cashondelivery::PAYMENT_METHOD_CASHONDELIVERY_CODE) {
            $allItems = $quote->getAllItems();
            /** @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
            foreach ($allItems as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->getData('engraving_services')) {
                    $result->setData('is_available', false);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much !!!

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

> Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="payment_restrictions" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodActiveObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Observer/PaymentMethodActiveObserver.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as paymentData;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;

class PaymentMethodActiveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    private $helperData;
    /**
     * @var paymentData
     */
    private $paymentData;

    /**
     * PaymentMethodActiveObserver constructor.
     * @param Data $helperData
     * @param paymentData $paymentData
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $helperData,
        paymentData $paymentData
    ) {
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
        $this->paymentData = $paymentData;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        /** @var DataObject $result */
        $result = $observer->getResult();
        /** @var AbstractMethod $methodInstance */
        $methodInstance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
        /** @var CartInterface $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $paymentCode = $methodInstance->getCode();

        $storeId = $quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null;

        if ($paymentCode == 'cashondelivery') {
            $notAllow = [] 
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $engravingServices = $item->getProduct()->getEngravingServices(); 
                if ($engravingServices) {
                   $notAllow[] = $engravingServices;
                }
            }

            if (!empty($notAllow)) {
               $result->setIsAvailable(false);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much !!!

Comment: Welcome.......:)